# Maven versions plugin: use "ignore" rules from parent project

Tags: java, maven, versions-maven-plugin

Preface: I've taken over a historically grown multi-module maven project. Now it's time to clean up the dependency versions. Since using version ranges has its problems (first of all, they don't work according to specs; second, they remove the reproducability of a build), I'm moving to introduce the versions-maven-plugin (v2.7).

Currently, I'm trying to get it to update the versions of dependency artifacts using the goal `versions:use-latest-releases`. It works for the most part, but it keeps finding beta versions to update to -- I'm surprised that they apparently count as "release". I managed to configure the plugin in the super parent pom (a `pom.xml` in a pom-packaged artifact appropriately named `super`), which all modules and submodules refer to as parent (sometimes indirectly). I found the [option to refer to an xml file containing rules to ignore specific versions or version patterns](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html#rulesUri) -- sadly, I cannot put the rules directly into the super parent pom (or I haven't found the option yet).

So here's the question I ended up with: How do I reference a file (according to the docs: "using a wagon URI or classpath URI") that sits next to the `pom.xml` of the super parent artifact which is packaged in pom format to be installed in Nexus? According to my research, this is not possible.

So let me put it broader: How do I *centrally* configure the versions-maven-plugin across a multi-module maven project tree to ignore all versions matching the regex `.*-b.*`?

Ideally, I would not even have to import the super project into my workspace nor have that file laying around on a webserver (I want it associated with the super project, not flying around somewhere).

Comment: About which specs are you talking about?

Comment: @khmarbaise The "2.0 design docs" mentioned in this 11 years old maven issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092 (tl;dr: contrary to the design docs you cannot specify a version range that ignores SNAPSHOT versions. Furthermore, one cannot add more patterns to the ignore list to also filter out alpha, beta, milestone, etc releases.)